# Datasource organization for UITableView with multiple types of UITableviewCells (complex)

Tags: ios, uitableview, datasource

I'm looking to improve my way of working, as I seem to be using a pattern that might be "best in class", or there is a much better way of doing it. Looking for advice.

Context: I need to show many types of rows: headers, totals, customers, projects, etc, but the counts and sequences change.

Calculating which row was what became to complex.

So I created a dataObject that represents possible cell content, with an enum type, indicating what cell content this specific dataObject represents.

(pseudocode)

```
dataobject:NSObject{
    @property cellType 
    @property... storage for other info relevant to the eventual CustomCell
}
```

I than generate an array with many dataObjects in the relevant sequence:

```
  - dataObject {cellType = header}
   - dataObject {celltype = customer}
   - dataOb.....
```

number of rows this way is equal to the object count.

I generate the UITableviewCell by retrieving the dataObject at the specific index, check what type it is, and return a CustomCell of that type.

I even use the dataObject as a multifunctional container, to contain information needed to be displayed in the cells. As all Cells have a common parent, they know how to read a dataObject,and display the information for their specific CustomCell type.

I hope it's clear...

anyone know a better solution ?

Comment: I think this approach is perfectly clear. I just wouldn't use that cellType you have on your model for two reasons: a model has to be totally transparent to the view, so it should not care where it will be displayed (maybe a different name for the property would be enough) and another reason you don't need it is that you can directly ask for the class type of your models, which would be enough to distinguish them (because I understand you are subclassing a common class for each kind of data object, right?).

Comment: I assume your table is just one section? I did a very similar thing and its working just fine. CellType is just that - its value that tells you how to draw the cell, or what kind of cell it is. Yoy may have 1 to 1 relationship from your data model to your cellType, or you may have few cellTypes as some are used for multiple model types. In my case I had multiple sections, so each data object had information on what the number of cells to show etc.